# AS3 How to make a shape appear over everything

Tags: actionscript-3

I am creating a drawing application and it's going pretty well - besides the fact there's a little glitch allowing you to draw over the toolbar. It only happens when the size of the lines are thick, and the thing I want is to make all the lines drawn over the toolbar go under the toolbar (the toolbar is just a regular rectangle shape). For example  Is there a piece of code to make it appear over everything? And I won't use drawRect because that would hide all the movieclips on top of it.

Comment: Your question is super unclear. First you want to make a shape appear *over* everything, and then you don't want to use `drawRect` because it would hide the stuff under it? Isn't that the point of drawing over *everything*?

Comment: drawRect would hide the movieclips, and lines drawn by the user. Although I did phrase it awkwardly, I want the drawn lines to appear below it, and the movieclips to appear above it.  -- Although if there is one specific piece of code to make an object appear over everything, I could just add it to the movieclips aswell; I am a newbie at as3 and I don't know much code yet.

Answer (score 0):

> I want is to make all the lines drawn over the toolbar go under the toolbar

It's question about managing display list. First of all read about [Display list](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/display_list_programming_as3.html)

Place display object with your toolbar over display object where user draws.

```
addChild(myCanvasToDraw);
addChild(myToolbar);
```